# Issues in handling touches on subviews(uiviews) in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitouch, touches

I have craeted a UIScrollView using code and i have created subviews which i am creating dynamically from the DB that are added to the  array of views and to the UIScrollviews.I am using touchesBegan and touchesMoved methods.The subview which i am selecting is not recognized,but the control comes into touchesBegan and touches moved method.I have posted the code below.Please anybody help me to overcome from this issue.

I have created the scrollview through code and i have subviews in an array named "arrayofviews".these subviews are the same views which are in the array.I am able to move these subviews which are from the DB on a normal view,but when i added these views to the scrollview its not working.

I have tried so many solutions which are in the net,but i couldn't get a proper solution.

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

 scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 374)];
 scrollview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 [scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
 [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 600)];
 scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
 scrollview.delaysContentTouches=NO;

    .
 .
 .
 .
    //here i am retrieving the controls from the DB and adding into the "arrayofviews" array which is an NSMutableArray

    //I have added subviews in this part to the scroll like
    [scrollview addSubview:vw1];

    [scrollview addSubview:vw2];

 .
 .
 .

 scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
 scrollview.scrollEnabled=FALSE;
 [self.view addSubview:scrollview];

 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollview];


}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
 [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

 CGPoint touchLocation;
 touchLocation.x=scrollview.contentOffset.x;
 touchLocation.y=scrollview.contentOffset.y;
 for(UIView *vw in arrayOfViews)
 {
  vw.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
  if([touch view]==vw)
  {
   vw.center=touchLocation;
  }
 }

}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  //method to intiate the touch events
{
 [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event]; 
 UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:scrollview] anyObject];
 CGPoint touchLocation1;
 touchLocation1.x=scrollview.contentOffset.x;
 touchLocation1.y=scrollview.contentOffset.y;
 for(UIView *vw in arrayOfViews)
 {
  if([touch view]==vw)
  {
   vw.center=touchLocation1;   //statement to move the control
  }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the line

scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

to

> scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

reason

userInteractionEnabled tells the device, whether to accept touch events. As you disabled the touch on scrollView then how it could recived touches events...

cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks for reply Waquas, but Touchevents method are getting fired.I want touches to be enabled for the subviews not the scrollview.

Comment: infact when you set userInteractionEnabled = NO; then user interaction also got disabled for subviews. and when user interaction is disabled then in turn touches events don't fired. Have a try.